# GitHub: deactivate notifications for one repository

Tags: email, github, notifications

Sorry, this is not really a development question but I don't know where to ask (SuperUser?)

I'm using my GitHub account for private and professional repositories and I'm getting about 40 email notifications a day for *one* repository I'm not interested in.

I tried to deactivate notifications for this repository but only found a way to deactivate notifications for *new* repositories.

Apart from setting up an email filter - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Github's site](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/configuring-notifications)

> You can configure notifications for a repository on the repository
> page, or on your watching page.

and

> You can customize notifications for a repository, for example, you can
> choose to only be notified when updates to one or more types of events
> (issues, pull request, releases, discussions) happen within a
> repository, or ignore all notifications for a repository. For more
> information, see "[Viewing your subscriptions.](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-your-subscriptions#configuring-your-watch-settings-for-an-individual-repository)"

And from what I have seen: [This is where you find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9FZp.png) Enter the repo, Settings, notifications, and you have the 'Active' checkbox.

Comment: Nice answer for a new contributor, quoting important part of helpful links and not only questioning the question itself :)

Comment: Thanks, I honestly just wanted the ability to upvote good answers on this site. I found really useful answers multiple times (which were not necessarily the accepted answer) which helped me and deserved my appreciation, but I couldn't until now. Hopefully they retroactively apply.

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2024, you can

1. go to https://github.com/watching
2. for each repository that you want to unsubscribe to, click on Unwatch, and then select "Ignore" from the popup menu: [image]
3. (optionally) go to your https://github.com/notifications and mark all of the existing notifications as read